# Multiple models in controller, what good practices with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently developing a web application using Ruby on Rails. I have a controller which get two parameters `:city` and `:sub_category`.
I've a model named `InterestPoint` which belongs to a `SubCategory` and a `City`

Using what I read on the web, I end up doing this to list all `InterestPoint` matching the city and the category :

```
class SubCategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @city = City.where(route_str: params[:city]).first
    @sub_category = SubCategory.where(route_str: params[:sub_category]).first
    @interest_point = InterestPoint.where(city_id: @city.id).where(sub_category_id: @sub_category.id)
  end

end
```

My models :

```
class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interest_points
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interest_points
end

class InterestPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category
  belongs_to :city
end
```

Here is the route concerned :

```
get '/:city/:sub_category/' => 'sub_category#index'
```

It's running well, but RubyMine (my IDE) keeps telling me this is a bad practice : Only one model per controller should be used.

So, my question is, why is it a bad practice, and how can I do it "the right way" ?

**My answer based on khaled_gomaa one :**

**Step 1**, moved from SubCategory Controller to InterestPoint Controller since it's what the page is about.

**Step 2**, created scopes inside my InterestPoint Model :

```
scope :by_location, lambda { |str|
  joins(:city).where('cities.route_str = ?', str)
}

scope :by_category, lambda { |str|
  joins(:sub_category).where('sub_categories.route_str = ?', str)
}
```

**Step 3**, added Index action to my InterestPoint Controller :

```
def index
   @interest_points = InterestPoint.by_location(params[:city]).by_category(params[:sub_category]).load
end
```

Comment: What is the name of the controller?

Comment: SubCategory, because it's the last parameter in my URL. Is this bad too ?

Comment: I just need to understand the whole picture to be able to help you with why this is not the right way to do it. ok so you have your url like this /city/sub_category right?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post with the route.

Comment: this page should display the interest points only? or will display stuff related to the city and sub category. I mean what is the main hero of the page is it the sub category or the interest points as i feel the interest points is the main aim of that action?

Comment: This page displays the list of all the InterestPoints matching both city and sub_category.

Comment: Then you should have an action `index` in a controller named `interest_points_controller` and simply play with city id and sub category id. Use before filters to load the instance of the other models if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I've got from you.

1. This controller should be InterestPoints Controller as its main
   function is to display a list of all Interest points.
2. The interest point model should contain a method to
   retrieve all interest points located in a given city and falling
   under a given sub category and you just call it in the controller.

So you'll have something like this

```
class InterestPointsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @interest_point = InterestPoint.located(params[:city]).categorized(params[:sub_category])
  end
end
```

where in located and categorized are scopes in the interest point model

Comment: Just a last little question, how can I get the City and the SubCategory object now from the controller, since there is no more city and sub_category ? To displays their names in the view ?

Comment: if you say InterestPoint.includes(:city, :sub_category).locat...... you will have the city and sub category on all you can use any of them